# How to deploy web project on remote tomcat server outside Eclipse with .jar files in it

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, tomcat, jpa

I have Rest **API Project A** which uses Project B and Project C for Database retrieval

**Project B**, **Project c** In which JPA is used for DB. Project A is working in Eclipse as i have added Project B and Project C's dependency at following places:

1. Properties -> **Deployment Assembly**--> Add -> Project B and C
2. **Debug Configurations** -> Classpath -->User Entries --> Add Projects B and C which includes all .jars of B and C automatically
3. Added project B and C to **Projects--> Properties**

Now i want my web project to run on **Localhost without Eclipse.**

I made ProjectA.war file and put it in tomcate's webapps folder and run tomcat.

It performs normal function like if i want to print Hello. it does..

But when i try to run any function which in turn call project B and C's function which has query to Database JPA its Not working.It doesn't return any data.

After Deploying .war in tomcat In Project A `webapps\ProjectA\WEB-INF\lib` only .jar which i added in `Properties -> Deployment Assembly--> Add -> Project B and C` Appears.

How can i make it work to use project B and C also. Please Help what .jars or dependencies should i also need to include and where??

Comment: Are there any errors in your logs?

Comment: No it just returns NULL at place of returned data

Comment: Does it work in Eclipse?  Are you using the same DB?

Comment: yes it works in eclipse and i am using same DB

Answer (score 1):

You need to create jars for your project B & C an place them under the WEB-INF\lib of your project A in tomcat webapps directory.

Or if you don't create jars for your project B & C then copy the classes with proper package structures in WEB-INF/classes.

You can always check what is going wrong in Tomcat/logs directory.

**A piece of advice:**
Familarize yourself with use of build tools such as maven and ant. I would recommend you to learn about maven, its dependency management, and build plugins. You can really make your life easier with such tools.

Comment: 1st Option i have tried it didn't work. let me try other two things

Comment: @Shiv First thing should also work if you create your jars properly and put htem in the WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: i have created jar... whiile creating i checked-1. exported general class files and resuouces 2.export java source files and resources.. and choosed class files in project and later i sealed all required packages

Comment: @Shiv you should not dump the projects in classes folder, rather take the classes from the projects taget/bin folder and copy them using the same package dir structure.

Comment: @shiv can you paste your web application directory structure and your project a, b and c classes directory strucutre.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\PorjectA\WEB-INF\classes\org\com

and then ALL three Projects

1. Project A

2. Project B
3. Project C

Comment: org\com\projectB and org\com\ProjectC org\com\Project A its my project structure

Comment: @Shiv This part org\com\projectB and org\com\ProjectC org\com\Project A is looking problematic to me. Take the classes from each of the projects and place directly under WEB-INF\classes and not under org\com\. It will be better if you can show me the classes strucuture of each of this projects.

Comment: If you are not getting error logs then I suggest that your class structure is correct.  I wonder whether configuration is correct though.  Are you sure you are using the same DB.  Can you insert data? Can you add more debugging information?