# Refer one spring project into other spring mvc project in sts

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I working on one spring mvc project and used the methods of other spring project. example :

one project "***DependencyCheck***" and second project is of spring mvc named "***SpringExplore***".

I have added the first project i.e **DependencyCheck** in build path and used it method in home controller that is the part of second project named "***SpringExplore***" .but it throws exception. Please find the snapshot

[image]

and exception thrown :

[image]

Note:[i am working with STS(spring tool suite)].Please let me know the solution.

Comment: Are you sure the JAR is presented in the generated WAR ?

Comment: I am running it with sts. and if class not found is there it means at run time class is not available.so this is my question whether it is possible or not.

Comment: I suspect what is happening is Since you have a POM when the application is being generated STS might be building based only on the POM. Check this question if it helps, though this is eclipse specific. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005644/classnotfoundexception-when-using-user-libraries-in-eclipse-build-path