# Java SOAP WSDL service NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have been struggling with the creation of a SOAP web service and I simply can't get it working.

I have written my service, and then, from Eclipse, I created a Web service. And although the saving in the db worked just fine when I tested the service locally (created a simple main method), when I try testing it from the generated Web service I get NoClassDefFoundError.

If anyone has the time to take a look I would be gratefull.
https://dane289@bitbucket.org/dane289/soapservice_problems.git

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you check following instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005644/classnotfoundexception-when-using-user-libraries-in-eclipse-build-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that eclipse was not adding the jars to the WAR file. 
After adding them to the war via the eclipse menu Assembly something everything worked fine.