# Class not found in Runtime in Eclipse while Maven Dependency already included

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I use maven to download the ojdbc.jar dependency. 
The jar already appeared in **Maven Dependencies** in **Eclipse** which I guess it is ready for use. But when I try to import **OracleDriver**, Eclipse cannot help me to import the class and show error on the line.

I tried `Class.forName("oracle.driver.OracleDriver")` for searching the class. It also shows the exception of **ClassNotFound**.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.techoffice.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>OracleJdbcExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Sample Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at com.techoffice.oracle.OracleJdbcAppl.main(OracleJdbcAppl.java:18)
```

Comment: I have tried to copy the jar into a folder named lib and let eclipse reference the jar. Eclipse still cannot find the class.

Comment: I have tried to use ojdbc7 downloaded from oracle homepage and reference it by build path. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Due to Oracle license restrictions, the Oracle JDBC driver is not available in the public Maven repository. To use the Oracle JDBC driver with Maven, you have to download and install it manually into your Maven local repository.

Use the following command for installation:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={{Full path to your jar}}
           -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Or you can use [Oracle Maven Repository](https://maven.oracle.com/):

The Oracle Maven repository requires a valid user registration and the
user should also accept the terms and conditions by logging
into http://maven.oracle.com. This username will be used in
`settings.xml`.

Create a `settings-security.xml` file that holds the master password information under the local  maven repository (Example: `{USER_HOME}/.m2/`) that is usually under the user home directory.  For example: If the username is test then the path will be

Unix : `/home/test/.m2/settings.xml`

Windows : `C:\Users\test\.m2\settings.xml`

The `settings.xml` file is required for downloading Oracle JDBC drivers and UCP.  Encrypt the user password before using it in `settings.xml`.  Use the following commands to encrypt the user password and update `settings.xml`:

`mvn -encrypt-password <any_master_password>` or `mvn -ep <any_master_password>`

[Source of the information](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides)

Comment: But I use third party repo to download it... https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo

Comment: @Ben Cheng Did you check your classpath variable? Sometimes IDE is not fully synchronized with build tools, and has its own settings to build project

Comment: I use eclipse and reference the jar

Comment: Thanks. I use Eclipse as IDE. I do not know how to check the classpath variable. Is that the build path config or the run configuration of classpath?

Comment: @Ben Cheng maybe this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005644/classnotfoundexception-when-using-user-libraries-in-eclipse-build-path

Answer (score 0):

Download the "ojdbc6.jar" file to your PC. `cd` into the folder where it has been downloaded. Then use this command to install the library on your maven local repository (usually your `~/.m2` directory):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

After this, Eclipse should be able to seamlessly find the dependency.

Comment: It is already downloaded from maven by third-party repo. Besides, I have tried to reference it instead of using maven. Still not work. But it works for ojdbc7 download from Oracle Homepage.

Answer (score -1):

```
Include the ojdbc6.jar file in the Deployment Assembly of the Project

Right Click on project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add your ojdbc6.jar file in it
```

Method2:
    Right Click on Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add External JAR -> add the ojdbc6.jar

Comment: It is not web application project.

Comment: Can you please try the above?

Comment: As it is not Web Application Project. there are no way to try this.

Comment: Right Click on Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add External JAR -> add the ojdbc6.jar